# Smart Pointer Syntax for New

Tags: c++, pointers

Trying to create a shared pointer and keep getting a "expected a type specifier" what could be causing this?

```
#ifndef ROOM_HPP
#define ROOM_HPP
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

#include "Pocket.hpp"


using namespace std;

class Room
{
protected:
    Room *up;
    Room *down;
    Room *left;
    Room *right;
    string name;

    shared_ptr<Pocket> p(new Pocket());
```

Comment: You can't use `( )` for an initializer in this context; use `{ }` instead

Answer (score 0):

A parentheses initializer is not allowed by the syntax for a member declaration.  Instead you may use curly braces or an equal sign:

```
shared_ptr<Pocket> p{new Pocket()};
```

or

```
shared_ptr<Pocket> p = shared_ptr<Pocket>(new Pocket());
```

You may also want to consider [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), which is the preferred way of creating a `shared_ptr` with default deleter:

```
shared_ptr<Pocket> p = std::make_shared<Pocket>();
```